# Angularjs 2 How to install Modal popup and used

Tags: angularjs

I am new from **`Angularjs2`** How to install **`Modal Popup`** in My project and how to use it in template.

Plese tell me the procedure

Comment: What are you talking about ? What is `modal popup` ? What is your template ?

Comment: I want this way in my project https://embed.plnkr.co/82m6AK5JydT9uRnreDZz/

Comment: I think you got it here (http://www.angulartypescript.com/angular-2-modal-salesforce/). You have all the instructions concerning "installation" of this kind of modal